# Discord bot automatically shuts off

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been making a discord bot for some time and I recently added a kick feature to it, but whenever I use the command on someone with a higher role than the bot, the bot automatically shuts off. im using discord v12.22.1

here is my code btw

```
    const { member, mentions } = message

    const tag = `<@${member.id}>`

    if (
      member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')
    ) {
      const target = mentions.users.first()
      if (target) {
        const targetMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id)
        targetMember.kick()
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
      .setDescription(`that user has been KICKED`);
    message.channel.send(embed);
      } else {
        message.channel.send(`${tag} Please specify someone to kick.`)
      }
    } else {
      message.channel.send(
        `${tag} You do not have permission to use this command.`
      )
    }
  })
})
```

and it gives me this error:

```
(node:339) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:339) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors? Are you using discord.js v12 or v13? We need more details.

Comment: yes it gives this very long error, : s/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
(node:339) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()., also im using discord v12.22.1

Comment: Could you add the error to the question so that readers can actually read and understand the error?

Comment: alright i did, now do you know how i can fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord.js has a simple solution for your problem.
Any guild member has a membber.kickable property, it will be true if you can kick them, and false if you cant.

This could be added to your code:

```js
if (!targetMember.kickable) {
    return message.channel.send("I cannot kick that user!")
}
```

Your final code would look something like

```js
const { member, mentions } = message;
const tag = `<@${member.id}>`;

if(member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) {
    const target = mentions.users.first();
    if(target) {
        const targetMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);

        if(!targetMember.kickable) {
            return message.channel.send("I cannot kick that user!");
        }

        targetMember.kick();
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setDescription(`that user has been KICKED`);
        message.channel.send(embed);

    }else{
        message.channel.send(`${tag} Please specify someone to kick.`)
    }
}else{
    message.channel.send(`${tag} You do not have permission to use this command.`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use `<member>.kick(...).catch(...)` to catch any errors that `<member>.kick(...)` may throw at you.

Example:

```js
const member = await (client.guilds.fetch(message.guild.id)).members.cache.get(message.author.id); // Get the member

if (member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) { // Make sure the user had permission to kick members
    const target = message.mentions.users.first(); // Get the user to kick
    if (target) { // If the target exists
        const targetMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id); // Get the targets guild member data
        targetMember.kick({ reason: 'enter-reason-here' }).catch(() => message.channel.send('I don\'t have permissions to kick ' + target.id); // Kick a member and if failed, tell the user that executed the command
    }
}
```

Full Example:

```js
const member = await (client.guilds.fetch(message.guild.id)).members.cache.get(message.author.id); // Get the member
const tag = `<@${member.user.id}>`; // Get the members user ID

if (member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) { // Make sure the user had permission to kick members
    const target = message.mentions.users.first(); // Get the user to kick
    if (target) { // If the target exists
        const targetMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id); // Get the targets guild member data
        targetMember.kick({ reason: 'enter-reason-here' }).catch(() => message.channel.send('I don\'t have permissions to kick ' + target.id); // Kick a member and if failed, tell the user that executed the command
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('RANDOM')
          .setDescription(`that user has been KICKED`);
        message.channel.send(embed); // Send the success embed
    } else
        message.channel.send(`${tag} Please specify someone to kick.`); // If the user didn't mention a user to kick
} else
    message.channel.send(`${tag} You do not have permission to use this command.`); // Tell the member they don't have permission to use the command
```